# Linq and arrays.(does e=element?)

Tags: c#, linq

```
from e in employees
where e.MonthlySalary >= 4000M && e.MonthlySalary <= 6000M
select e;
```

Does e= element in this situation, or does it state something different?

Comment: It just gives you a naming to "the current element". If you had no name for it, you couldn't filter with a `where` clause, because you couldn't reference the general element in the condition. You could name it however you like (or at least just as a normal variable within the scope).

Comment: I think I see. So the e is just an object of the employees array. Am I right in that regard?

Answer (score 3):

`e` is just an alias you set referring the resulting set of your query.

You can name it `chocolateSprinkles` if you want, the point is it's there to make your life easier. :)

This will produce the exact same result as your original code:

```
// The raddest of the rad dudes.
from radDudes in employees
where radDudes.MonthlySalary >= 4000M && radDudes.MonthlySalary <= 6000M
select radDudes;
```

C# developers typically use single letter variables in these Linq queries, because it's simpler to type and read at a glance. Since the variable is generally not used anywhere outside of the Linq query, sometimes people just use a single letter.

I *do* suggest using a descriptive name. In your case, instead of `e` you could have used `employee` as it's more readable.

```
// Which is more readble?
where e.MonthlySalary >= 4000M && e.MonthlySalary <= 6000M

// or:
where employee.MonthlySalary >= 4000M && employee.MonthlySalary <= 6000M
```

---

As a side note, you can also use this Linq syntax. It's entirely personal preference:

```
var resultEmployees = employees.Where(e => e.MonthylSalary >= 4000M && e.MonthlySalary <= 6000M);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you copied this from somewhere, `e` is arbitrary. If `employees` is a list of employees, then someone probably chose `e` to represent a single employee.

As a side note, you could also rewrite that as:

```
employees.Where(e => e.MonthlySalary >= 4000M && e.MonthlySalary <= 6000M)
```

... which can sometimes be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
from e in employees ...
```

Is basically the same as

```
foreach(var e in employees) { ... }
```

This illustrates what others are saying: that `e` is just a variable name for the current element of the set.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, that `e` can be anything you want it to be. You can call it `x, y, z`, etc. Its represents the object within your list. So in your example `e` refers to the a `employee` object.
So you can say `e.MonthlySalary` or `e.EmployeeName` etc, and it will match all employees on those conditions

Comment: Not really the object type, but the general object of it - a reference to "the current" object, in the logic of iterating over it.